# url error after uploading image on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress template and everything was working ok till when i try to add a photo for each product but it's not working when i inspect the image the url is wrong..how to change it?

the shown url : https://localhost:81/soraya/81/soraya/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/product-19-268x290.jpg

instead of : https://localhost:81/soraya/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/product-19-268x290.jpg

Thank You!

Comment: you are giving localhost url?? you have to put image instead of localhost url

Comment: that's the url of the image!

Comment: Try to find the code generating the link in the template and share it here.